# Subgraph position issues when using cluster_

Tags: graphviz

I've just discovered GraphViz and I'm trying to create a reasonably simple network diagram following on from the docs and examples.

So, I've tried splitting it into 3 main categories, and I want the 3 categories to be laid out from top to bottom: hypervisors -> core -> edge.

The following code renders great, but if I try and convert `subgraph core` to `subgraph cluster_core` it goes a little fubar. Suddenly the `core` moves to the left, the nodes are arranged vertically (Tried overriding with `rankdir` and `rank=same` for the nodes) - But I really want the outer border and label! Am I missing something here? Is the problem in between the chair and the computer?

The code I have so far is:

```
digraph network {
  graph [overlap = false]

  // Node definitions
  subgraph core {
    rank = same
    labelloc = c
    label = "Core"

    node [shape=square]
      SR_CORE DR_CORE

    node [shape=plaintext]
      ROUTE2 ROUTE1

  }

  subgraph cluster_hypervisors {
    rank = same
    labelloc = c
    style = filled
    label = "Hypervisors"

    node [shape=circle style=filled fillcolor=white]
      NODE01 NODE02 NODE03 NODE04
  }

  subgraph cluster_edge {
    rank = same
    labelloc = c
    label = "Edge"

    node [shape=rectangle]
      SWITCH01 SWITCH02 SWITCH03
  }

  // Edge definitions
  SR_CORE -> ROUTE2 -> DR_CORE [dir=none]
  SR_CORE -> ROUTE1 -> DR_CORE [dir=none]

  SR_CORE -> { SWITCH01 SWITCH02 }
  DR_CORE -> { SWITCH03 }

  NODE01 -> SR_CORE [dir=back]
  NODE02 -> SR_CORE [dir=back]
  NODE03 -> DR_CORE [dir=back]
  NODE04 -> DR_CORE [dir=back]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group nodes in `cluster_core` using `{}`. To adjust appearance you can also add some `constraint=false` to few edges:

```
digraph network {
  graph [overlap = false]

  // Node definitions
  subgraph cluster_core {
    rank = same
    labelloc = c
    label = "Core"

    node [shape=square]
      SR_CORE DR_CORE

    node [shape=plaintext]
      ROUTE2 ROUTE1

    {SR_CORE DR_CORE ROUTE2 ROUTE1}
  }

  subgraph cluster_hypervisors {
    rank = same
    labelloc = c
    style = filled
    label = "Hypervisors"

    node [shape=circle style=filled fillcolor=white]
      NODE01 NODE02 NODE03 NODE04
  }

  subgraph cluster_edge {
    rank = same
    labelloc = c
    label = "Edge"

    node [shape=rectangle]
      SWITCH01 SWITCH02 SWITCH03
  }

  // Edge definitions
  SR_CORE -> ROUTE2 [dir=none]
  SR_CORE -> ROUTE1 [dir=none, constraint=false]
  ROUTE2 -> DR_CORE [dir=none, constraint=false]
  ROUTE1 -> DR_CORE [dir=none, constraint=false]

  SR_CORE -> { SWITCH01 SWITCH02 }
  DR_CORE -> { SWITCH03 }

  NODE01 -> SR_CORE [dir=back]
  NODE02 -> SR_CORE [dir=back]
  NODE03 -> DR_CORE [dir=back]
  NODE04 -> DR_CORE [dir=back]
}
```

[image]

You can check working example on http://graphviz.it/#/mRSLblIF

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, I seem to have stopped receiving SO notifications to my email and haven't logged on in a while.

Thanks for the help, I didn't realise I'd missed that! I now see the power in edge constraints too!